# Should we have an appendix tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I went to add [appendix](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/appendix) to this post: [Should I include an appendix for inessential, yet related worldbuilding to my story?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/46021/should-i-include-an-appendix-for-inessential-yet-related-worldbuilding-to-my-st)

But that tag doesn't exist.  If there's something else that means the same thing, or includes appendices, I can't find it.

Including this post, [there are 21 questions with the word appendix](https://writing.stackexchange.com/search?q=appendix%20is%3Aq).  Plus another [4 questions that use the word appendices](https://writing.stackexchange.com/search?q=appendices%20-appendix%20is%3Aq).
At quick glance, they're all legitimately about it.

Appendices are common parts of a book (or sometimes an article).  They are used in both fiction and nonfiction.  They are unrelated to epilogues or endings or anything else like that.

Similar existing tags:

- [indexing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indexing) which includes indexes but is not limited to them.
- [table-of-contents](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/table-of-contents)
- [forewords](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forewords)
- [glossaries](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/glossaries) which is a type of appendix.

**I propose that I create a new tag called [appendix](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/appendix).  Then we can either leave [glossaries](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/glossaries) as separate or make it a synonym.**

Comment: While I approve of the Secespitus' excellent checklist for adding  "Appendix" -- do we need ones for other backmatter/front matter, or perhaps merely  "front matter" to cover indexes/forwards/dedications?

Comment: My question is: why appendix (singular) and glossaries (plural)?

Comment: @NofP Because appendices is a funny word.  Seriously that's the reason.

Comment: I've gone ahead and created the tag plus wiki guidance.

Comment: I'm done with retagging.  Ended up with 13 questions with the tag.

Answer (score 6):

## Yes we should add the tag.

Using [Secespitus' excellent tag creation question](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1498/33442) for this situation.

**1. Ask yourself how many questions you have about this topic: is this probably the only one or is this a topic you want to ask about more regularly?**

I don't think I am likely to ask questions on this topic, but I can see how it would be useful for users with a more technical writing focus. - Neutral

**2. Look through the existing questions: how many already use the word or similar words and might profit from the tag?**

You've already found 25 questions that would use this tag. That's a pretty strong case for adding it. - Plus

**3. Look through the existing tags: is one of them already encompassing what you are trying to convey?**

Of the 4 tags you mention as being related, only [glossaries](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/glossaries) could really be considered to be the same. Even then I believe [glossaries](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/glossaries) is the subcategory of [appendix](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/appendix) and we should have the larger tag. - Plus

**4. Look through Meta: have there been similar requests or precedent cases where something similar has been created/denied?**

Nothing related to appendices on meta. We have a [question about an epilogues tag](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1932/33442) which could be considered the [fiction](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fiction) equivalent of this [non-fiction](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-fiction) term. We decided to create that one, so I think that is a positive reason to create this one. - Plus

**5. Think about the sites scope: do you think that a lot of people will profit from these tags when they are asking questions about the specific topic of the site you are on?**

This tag is certainly on topic and is useful for a variety of users. - Plus

**6. Think about the tag's scope: is it well-defined and obvious to users coming to the site?**

To me this one is pretty obvious even without a defined tag wiki. If you are asking about anything to do with the [appendix](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/appendix) of a work you use the tag. Nothing to complicated about that. - Plus

By my guess that makes 5 pluses and a neutral which should be more than enough justification to create the tag. Go ahead and create it.

---

## Suggested tag wiki

Tag Info:

> This tag is for questions about appendices in written work. Formatting, usage and best practices for writing appendices should all use this tag.

Tag Wiki:

> An appendix is a section of additional information as the end of a book of document. This tag should be used for any questions that relate to the use of appendices. Questions on formatting, proper usage, and referencing them, all come under this tag.
>
> Examples of questions that should use this tag:
>
> - [Is the order of appendices according to their references fixed?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/5243/33442)
> - [Should I include an appendix to reference words of an in-universe language for a fantasy novel?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/42761/33442)
> - [Are TOC and appendix part of total word count for books?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/7056/33442)
>
> Related tags: [glossaries](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/glossaries) [forewords](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forewords) [indexing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indexing) [table-of-contents](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/table-of-contents)

---

## The Glossaries tag should remain

Glossaries is indeed a sub-category of appendices, however I believe it is distinct enough that it should remain its own tag. The [three questions that use it](https://writing.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bglossaries%5D+is%3Aq) are distinctly about glossaries, not appendices in general. For now I think we should leave it. At a later time if we decide that it serves no functional purpose is will be simple to make it a synonym of [appendix](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/appendix).

Comment: +1 I agree with your assessment on this one, except for "25 questions being a strong case".

Answer (score 1):

I'm in favor of the concept. However, I'm not sure we'd need **both** [appendix](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/appendix) and [epilogue](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/epilogue) as distinct tags.

**I'd suggest creating a general** [end-matter](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/end-matter) tag. (Which could use that term, or some other one. I'm absolutely open to suggestions here.) We can then **synonymize** [appendix](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/appendix) and [epilogue](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/epilogue) to it.

That way, we don't have different tags for what amounts to basically the same concept depending on whether you're writing fiction or non-fiction. The combination with other tags, such as [creative-writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/creative-writing) or [fiction](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fiction) or [technical-writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-writing) or [academic-writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/academic-writing) or what have you should be what conveys the type of writing you're doing, not the choice of one tag or another for the same concept. Besides using tags more the way they feel to me like they are intended, it also seems likely to help international users who don't have English as their first language, or who aren't even writing in English in the first place.

Comment: [tag:appendix] and [tag:epilogue] are different things though.  An appendix is information the author includes at the end of the book or the article that is relevant but not right for the body of the work.  In fiction, it can be part of the story or outside it (research oriented).  An epilogue is just in fiction (or some nonfiction like biography) which follows up on the characters or setting in some way.  It's part of the story.

Comment: @Cyn But is the distinction major enough that we can't have one tag that (in combination with specification of the type of work) would work for both?

Comment: I think they are distinct enough.  1) There's basically no overlap (none in fiction and little in nonfiction) and 2) There is no pre-existing word or phrase that covers both.  Yes, we could make one up, as you tried, but getting people to use it might be hard, as the search process only looks for names of tags, not synonyms* or descriptions.  * = synonyms only come up in searches if you're in the middle of tagging the question.

Answer (score 1):

We should keep [glossaries](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/glossaries) as a separate tag and cross-link the wikis.

- Questions about glossary entries aren't necessarily questions about *the glossary*.  In online documentation glossary entries can be pop-outs; there might not be a compiled glossary at all.
- Even if there is, the concepts of "front" and "back" are much weaker in online formats like wikis or context-sensitive help.  Instead, people jump around, search, follow links, and otherwise read content non-sequentially.
- In printed books, I've occasionally seen a glossary at the beginning of a novel (sometimes accompanied by maps and/or family trees).